# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/myproject/mymodule/ClassName in Android Instrumented Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, noclassdeffounderror, android-testing, instrumented-test

can anyone help to solve this problem?
Previously, i try to create a instrumented test for my project. I create new module for unit test and an error occurred in the module when I created the class, then I generated class to create an instrumented test (stored in the package `com.module.unit_test (androidTest)`) but why when I run `ResourceComparer` class which is in the same package it gets error as in the title?

`ResourceComparer.kt`:

```
package com.ichwan.unit_test

import android.content.Context

class ResourceComparer {

    fun isEqual(context: Context, resId: Int, compare: String) : Boolean {
        return context.getString(resId) == compare
    }
}
```

`ResourceComparerTest.kt`:

```
package com.ichwan.unit_test

import android.content.Context
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

class ResourceComparerTest {

    private lateinit var resourceComparer: ResourceComparer

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        resourceComparer = ResourceComparer()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown(){

    }

    @Test
    fun stringResourceSameAsGivenString_returnsTrue() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        val result = resourceComparer.isEqual(context, androidx.compose.ui.R.string.selected, "selected")
        assertThat(result).isTrue()
    }

    @Test
    fun stringResourceSameAsGivenString_returnsFalse() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        val result = resourceComparer.isEqual(context, androidx.compose.ui.R.string.selected, "selection")
        assertThat(result).isFalse()
    }
}
```

and this is result from logcat:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/ichwan/unit_test/ResourceComparer;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:111)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:91)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:74)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:43)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(AndroidJUnit4Builder.java:51)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:149)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.ScanningTestLoader.doCreateRunner(ScanningTestLoader.java:50)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:64)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:835)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:650)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:418)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ichwan.unit_test.ResourceComparer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.ichwan.unit_test.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ichwan.gigihmodule-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ichwan.gigihmodule-2/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ichwan.gigihmodule-2/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ichwan.unit_test.test-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.ichwan.gigihmodule-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 18 more
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.ichwan.gigihmodule-2/split_config.en.apk
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:373)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:113)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:78)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:359)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeElements(DexPathList.java:323)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:263)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:126)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:520)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:553)
at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1847)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:766)
at android.app.ContextImpl.<init>(ContextImpl.java:2066)
at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2011)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5252)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.ichwan.gigihmodule-2/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:373)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:113)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:78)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:359)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeElements(DexPathList.java:323)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:263)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:126)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:520)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:553)
at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1847)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:766)
at android.app.ContextImpl.<init>(ContextImpl.java:2066)
at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2011)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5252)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I've read several sources here, but most of them have additional dependencies from Gradle. but I'm confused if the error is as stated in the logcat, are there additional libraries or missing gradle scripts?

this is my `build.gradle (module)` scripts:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
android {
    namespace 'com.ichwan.unit_test'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ichwan.unit_test"
        minSdk 24
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":app")
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
}
```